# How come Snoke could force-connect Rey and Kylo but still not be able tell where Rey was?

Tags: star-wars, the-force, the-last-jedi, snoke

In *The Last Jedi*, when Rey is on an island with Luke Skywalker, we see Kylo Ren and Rey force-connecting, and later in the film, when they are together in Snoke's throne room, Snoke tells them he connected them, etc., ect.

But what caught my notice was that when Snoke starts throwing Rey around the room with the Force, he's shouting at her, telling her to "give him [the location of] Skywalker". So....

**How could Snoke have connected Rey to Kylo when Rey was on Luke's Island, and still not have found out where she was?**

Comment: Because the story in the new JJ/Ryan-trilogy doesn't make much sense?

Comment: @HansOlo Most likely.

Comment: The Sacred Jedi Texts say @HansOlo is correct.

Comment: @SillybutTrue Rey was going to that weird tree to look that up, but Luke distracted her.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Force connection seems to offer limited, if any, ability to track the other person.

In *The Rise of Skywalker*, for example, Rey and Kylo have been connected for about a year. When Kylo is on Kijimi, Rey is right above him in orbit, the two are actively dueling, and he *still* can't tell where she is until he sees Vader's helmet, which he kept in his room on his Star Destroyer (for some reason he didn't figure it out from her having the dagger that he kept in the same room).

Likewise, when Luke projects himself to Crait in *The Last Jedi*, he presumably wouldn't have had any way of knowing Crait's exact location, but he is still able to manifest his presence there.

A deleted scene in *Return of the Jedi* also showed Vader reaching out to Luke while he (Luke) was building a new lightsaber on Tatooine. Vader doesn't show any sign of being able to actually find Luke through this connection:

From these simliar examples, it's plausible that Snoke wouldn't have needed to know Rey's location in order to connect her with Kylo. This ability just seems to require that the user know who the other person is.